# Is there any online / free / simple tool doing focus stacking without a need to installing anything?

Tags: software-recommendation, service-recommendation, focus-stacking

I want to focus-stack 10 images of 20MPi each. I do not have a photoshop license and am looking for some light-weighted tool which does not need installation (don't have rights to install). Ideally, there are many online tools out there for different image manipulations (such as resize image online etc...). Is there any online focus stacking service? I tried to google one but there were none. Do you guys know about one?

Comment: I know you specifically said you don't rights to install software, but please clarify: do you have another computing device that you _do_ have rights to install software on? Perhaps a mobile phone or tablet? The point of my question is to distinguish answers along the lines of, "you're pretty much out of luck", from ones such as "not in the way you're asking, but if you're able to install a mobile/tablet app, you could try..."

Comment: Look for a so called "portable" version of the tool of your choice.

Comment: Thanks folks. It is a company pc, which has super tight access rights, browser on it and microscope is connected to it.

Comment: If you have access to internet, why don't you just use google drive or whatever to pass the photos to a computer with photoshop?

Comment: Perhaps http://www.picolay.de/download.htm

Comment: Understood, assumed it was locked-down PC. But can you transfer the images to another system (PC, phone, etc.) that isn't as locked-down, so you can install Helicon, ImageStacker, etc.?

Comment: If this is a work thing it would be quite reasonable to ask your IT group to install something suitable.  You shouldn't be floundering around trying to find some way to bypass your work restrictions .

Comment: Usually, IT departments understand to lock down PCs mostly running business productivity software, and leave software devs, science and graphics people to manage their own stuff (and keep it at a distance from the business stuff). If you are dual role, ask for two separate PCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps someone, I have used following site couple of times to focus stack images: https://focusstackingonline.com/.

I actually tried it also on mobile and it worked.

Comment: Maybe it used to work but now clicking to upload takes you to an online casino and "you have been chosen to win a prize" pages (that stuff your browser history, disabling the [Back] button).

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps you've got a web browser virus?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it, but you might look into Picolay. It has a "portable" install capability (i.e., no admin rights needed; run from anywhere)

http://picolay.de/download.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is a website [www.Photopea.com](https://www.Photopea.com), which is an advanced photo editor.

It can do focus-stacking, as described in [this article](https://www.photopea.com/tuts/focus-stack-images-online/). It runs on your computer, so you don't need to worry about uploading 200 MB of photos on a slow internet connection.

Unlike automatic tools, Photopea puts a mask on each layer, and you can edit these masks further, manually.

I am the author of Photopea and I would be glad to answer your questions! :)